# Why WBNB balance does not appear in bscscan?

Tags: metamask, wallets, smart-contract-wallets, binance-smart-chain, bscscan

I'm playing with WBNB, and when I make a deposit of BNB to [WBNB Smart Contract](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xae13d989dac2f0debff460ac112a837c89baa7cd#writeContract) I receive the same amount of WBNB to my wallet (I can see it in Metamask). Everything it's Ok.

The problem is that when I access to my wallet in bscbscan, the balance of WBNB does not appear. I can see the rest of my tokens, but not WBNB. I have waited some time, just in case it is a problem of real time but does not seem it.

Any idea about why happen this?

**UPDATE:** Seems to cache problem in the browser.

Comment: did you try adding WBNB contract address in metamask and see if tokens appear there?

Comment: Yes sure, I see WBNB in my Metamask wallet at the moment.